# brightness control not working

Tags: 14.04, brightness, intel

I have got a new Ubuntu update to 14.04 LTS on lenovo ideapad 500.

The brightness control buttons(i.e. <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>) aren't working. It has Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07).

Comment: did you try with combination of the function keys?

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

<kbd>fn</kbd> is found just beside the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem:

In case you don't have the following configuration file, open terminal and create it with following command

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Then you have to edit the file, any editor can be used, in this example it's  **nano**

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

When you have a text editor open, add these lines to the file

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Then save the file.

Now when you log out, and then log back in everything should work fine.

In more detail [here on ITSFOSS](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)